# Why is my Index always going out of bound whenever I try to display an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to modify a given code and add an average to all the elements within a user given 2d array. I'm initializing the array `ave` to have the same elements of array `sum` and then displaying it outside the `for` loop to do the calculation.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays2D_GeneratorRevised {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int R=4, C=3;
        int r,c;
        double[][] volt = new double[R][C];
        double[] sum = new double[R];
        double[] ave = new double[R];
        System.out.println("Enter the output voltages for the following generators :");
        for(r=0; r<R; r++) {
            System.out.print("Generator "+(r+1)+" :\n");
            for(c=0; c<C; c++) {
                volt[r][c]=in.nextInt();
                sum[r]+=volt[r][c];
                ave[r]+=sum[r];
            }
        }
        //display table
        System.out.print("\n\t           Generator Test Results");
        System.out.printf("\n\t%16s%10s%9s%10s","Output 1","Output 2","Output 3","Average");
        for(r=0; r<R; r++) {
            System.out.print("\nGenerator "+(r+1));
            for(c=0; c<C; c++) {
                System.out.printf("%10.2f",volt[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.printf("%10.2f",sum[r]/C);
        }
        System.out.printf("%10.2f",ave[r]/=(R*C));
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
}
```

I tried making the `ave` to a 2d array and assigning it different variables of R,C,c,r. This also happens whenever I make a 1d array and display it using the argument `array[i]`. Somehow it only works whenever I use the `Arrays.toString()` to display or manipulate the elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
for(r=0; r<R; r++)
{
    [...]
}
System.out.printf("%10.2f",ave[r]/=(R*C));
                            // ^ HERE
```

After the `for` loop, `r == R`, which is one past the end of the array.

Looking at the code, should that `printf` be inside the loop, not outside?

Comment: Shouldn't it be on the outside because I'm only doing the averaging once?

Answer (score 0):

If `ave` is supposed to be the average for all four generators, then your calculation is wrong. `ave` should be a scalar and not an array.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays2D_GeneratorRevised {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int R=4, C=3;
        int r,c;
        double[][] volt = new double[R][C];
        double[] sum = new double[R];
        double ave = 0.0;
        System.out.println("Enter the output voltages for the following generators :");
        for(r=0; r<R; r++) {
            System.out.print("Generator "+(r+1)+" :\n");
            for(c=0; c<C; c++) {
                volt[r][c]=in.nextInt();
                sum[r]+=volt[r][c];
                ave+=sum[r];
            }
        }
        //display table
        System.out.print("\n\t           Generator Test Results");
        System.out.printf("\n\t%16s%10s%9s%10s","Output 1","Output 2","Output 3","Average");
        for(r=0; r<R; r++) {
            System.out.print("\nGenerator "+(r+1));
            for(c=0; c<C; c++) {
                System.out.printf("%10.2f",volt[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.printf("%10.2f",sum[r]/C);
        }
        System.out.printf("%n%10.2f",ave/=(R*C));
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Here is a sample run:

```
Enter the output voltages for the following generators :
Generator 1 :
1 4 9
Generator 2 :
16 25 36
Generator 3 :
49 64 81
Generator 4 :
100 121 144

               Generator Test Results
            Output 1  Output 2 Output 3   Average
Generator 1      1.00      4.00      9.00      4.67
Generator 2     16.00     25.00     36.00     25.67
Generator 3     49.00     64.00     81.00     64.67
Generator 4    100.00    121.00    144.00    121.67
     99.67
```